# CSS: width of a <a>

Tags: css, image, background, width

I'm trying to do something pretty simple: an `<a>` tag with a background image. The code is found here, http://jsfiddle.net/QWatA/

The problem is that for some reason I can't set the width of the `<a>` tag in this code. If I had just a normal background and set it with a width it works fine. However seems like if I do it this way I have no control over the width. Ideally I want all the links to have highlights of the same width.

The reason I'm doing this is that I want a different background image for each of the links, so I'm forced to define all those `a.class1, a.class2` stuff.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not put the <a> around a <span> and style the span?

Comment: @Chris Farmer: What would that achieve? Then you just have an extra element... You could just apply the styles to the anchor.

Comment: @Chris Farmer: yes I would like to know as well... actually from my limited understanding this seems to be the way Google does it on their homepage's sidebar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block;` to your 'a' elements. By default 'a' is `display:inline` and so does not establish box with width/height.

http://jsfiddle.net/QWatA/1/

Comment: Thanks!! Wow can't believe I missed that one.

Answer (score 2):

yea c-smile beat me to it just put `display: block` in your css, however if your going to do `a.class1, a.class2` and so on with new pictures put it in your `ul li a` instead of in the `a.class1 a.class2` and so on then you only have to write the code once.